# How to validate a form request

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, form, validation

Is there anything with craft like [Laravel's Form Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#creating-form-requests)?

I am writing a plugin with a custom entry type. Right now, I am doing the store/edit pages and I do not want to reinvent the wheel ;)

Is there any way in craft/yii to easily validate the submitted values from a post request? Or what is the *best practice* in this case for craft?

Answer (score 1):

Yii 2 (which is what Craft 3 is built upon) has similar looking form/model validation:

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-validation

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-core-validators

You can also look at how Craft does it in its own [models](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/tree/develop/src/models) and [controllers](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/tree/develop/src/controllers).